# how to execute a script in node.js from within a js script

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have a js script that writes to a json file

```
"use strict";
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var file = 'data.json';
var obj = {name: 'andrew'};

jsonfile.writeFile(file, obj, function (err) {
console.error(err)
})
```

the problem is that this code only works if executed in node.js but i want to make a user interface in the browser that allows changing the content of the json file.
so for instance if the user clicked a button, the browser tells node server to execute the code. i am thinking that it might be possible through an http request but i have no clue on how to do that

Comment: -> https://expressjs.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the best way would probably be to do a http request as you dont want a user to write a file directly to the file system.

I would use expressjs (someone has given you the link in the comment) as to me its the simplest way of building a web application.

Define a route (most likely a POST) that takes in what you want to write to the file as the body. such as:

```
router.post('/write', postRequestHandler)

function postRequestHandler(req, res) {
    let contentToSave = req.body.jsonContent;

    jsonFile.writeFile(file, contentToSave, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
        } else {
            res.status(201).end()
        }
    })
}
```

Then define another route (GET) that returns the content of the json file.

You could then have a simple UI with 2 display sections one that shows the data available to edit and the data that is currently in the json file. then just have a couple of buttons, one calls POST with the content (so could be a "save" button) and the other calls GET (a "reload/retrieve" button)